# Spring Security - roles ain't working properly

Tags: java, spring, security

I've got a problem with Spring Security. I've created 3 roles (ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MOD, ROLE_USER). I am keeping the roles in database with passwords and usernames. In JSP I've created 3 different menus for all roles. In all menus there are 3 lines that repeats  "/messages", "/profile", "/logout". If I log as MOD or USER everything works fine , but If I log as ADMIN I can't access "/messages" and "/profile".

What is wrong with my config or jsp?

**security config:**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //@formatter:off
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/"
                    ,"/tutorials"
                    ,"/search"
                    ,"/about"
                    ,"/contact"
                    ,"/register",
                    "/css/*",
                    "/js/*",
                    "/img/*")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/messages",
                    "/profile",
                    "/logout",
                    "/newsmanager",
                    "/tutorialsmanager",
                    "/usersmanager",
                    "/sendemails"
                    )
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(
                    "/suggestnews",
                    "/suggesttutorial",
                    "/messages",
                    "/profile",
                    "/logout"
                    )
                .hasRole("MOD")
            .antMatchers(
                    "/messages",
                    "/profile",
                    "/logout"
                    )
                .hasRole("USER")
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll(); 

    //@formatter:on        
 }
```

**fragment of JSP:**

```
 <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"
            id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="true">
            Account <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="/messages">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="/tutorialsmanager">Tutorials manager</a></li>
            <li><a href="/newsmanager">News manager</a></li>
            <li><a href="/usersmanager">Users manager</a></li>
            <li><a href="/sendemails">Send emails</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:$('#logoutForm').submit();">Log
                    out</a></li>
        </ul>
</sec:authorize>

    <!--  APPEARED FOR ROLE_USER -->
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"
            id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="true">
            Account <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
            <li><a href="/messages">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:$('#logoutForm').submit();">Log
                    out</a></li>
        </ul>
</sec:authorize>

    <!--  APPEARED FOR ROLE_MOD -->
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_MOD')">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"
            id="dropdownMenu3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="true">
            Account <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
            <li><a href="/messages">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="/suggestnews">Suggest a news</a></li>
            <li><a href="/suggesttutorial">Suggest a tutorial</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:$('#logoutForm').submit();">Log
                    out</a></li>
        </ul>
</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: `hasRole` trims the `ROLE_` off the front. You're using `USER` in one spot and `ROLE_USER` in the other.

Comment: I'v changed it but still aint working.

Comment: Can you share the console log too.

Comment: Well I am not getting any errors from console. The only error is the whiteable page.

    Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Oct 23 11:08:27 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access is denied

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've managed to fix my problem. I changed the acces for profile,message and logout. Now all authenticated user can access it.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    //@formatter:off
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/"
                ,"/tutorials"
                ,"/search"
                ,"/about"
                ,"/contact"
                ,"/register",
                "/css/*",
                "/js/*",
                "/img/*")
                    .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(
                "/suggestnews",
                "/suggesttutorial")
                    .hasRole("MOD")
            .antMatchers(
                "/newsmanager",
                "/tutorialsmanager",
                "/usersmanager",
                "/sendemails"
                    .hasRole("ADMIN")
            **.antMatchers(
                "/messages",
                "/profile",
                "/logout")
            .authenticated()**  
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll(); 

        //@formatter:on     
}
```